# How to control the PFE Mailprinter?

Tags: drivers, installation, script, printing, printer

i have here a PFE Mailprinter. It is a device that takes printed documents from a printer (in this case the Koycera Ecosys FS-3750), folds it the letter-way and puts it in an envelope.

The problem: The device is from the 80'is. Not a bad thing in the first place (i am from the 80'is too ;-) ), but the company that produced it is not arround  anymore and there is very little to no evidence in the net that the device existet at all. :-(

What i have about the device: no driver, no manual. It is connected to the computer via LPT-port and the printer is connected to the mailprinter. What i found is that i have to put control charakters in the document that is about to be printed and the mailprinter axtracts it. Then sends the document to the printer. (likewise connected via LPT/centronics)

Also i have but one example of the control charakters:" !PFE;MMPAGES=2! "
A extended search on this returned nothing usefull at all. :-(

Last but not least: i dont know which driver i should use for the printer. If i use the original drivers from kyocera, the document gets stuck somewhere in the electronics of the mailprinter and nothing happens. Same goes for PostScript, PCL, Text Only and all other drivers i tried. At best it prints nonsense, but it is not reproducible under which conditions it does this. -.-

I seriously need help with this thing! Please help, someone!

Comment: what Operating System are we talking of here?

Comment: PFE is now part of Neopost. See if these guys can help: http://www.neoposttechnologies.co.uk . It looks as if they're only contactable by phone. Does the machine have a model number? Mailprinter is not found on their website.